# Hadoop map reduce- send the output of mapper to reduce only after all maps ran

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to send the output of my mapper in single computer only after all maps ran.

for example:

if computer #1 ran his map function 1000 times, I want the output to be sent once all 1000 maps happened.

Is there any way to do so?

EDIT- an explanation of why I want to do so:

I'm implementing the algorithm canopy.
My plan is to run canopy in each machine I have and find centroids of it's local data.

Once I find local centroids I want to send to reducer the local centroids and how many points related to them.

For example:
machine #1 found 3 centroids and each one of them has 30 views.
I would like to submit to reduce (centroid, views).
but the problem is that I will know the views only after all map funtions of the machine ran.
that's why I want to send the output of the machine mappers to reduce once all ran.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this, but there's definitely a configuration string you can set. I don't remember what it's called. We always left ours to the default (which I believe is 99% or 95%).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve something close to this would be to tune configuration property `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps`.  This setting is discussed in the Apache Hadoop documentation for [mapred-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml).

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps</name>
  <value>0.05</value>
  <description>Fraction of the number of maps in the job which should be 
  complete before reduces are scheduled for the job. 
  </description>
</property>
```

However, mistuning this setting is likely to harm your cluster's throughput.  Normally, the reducers can start fetching intermediate map outputs early from map tasks as they complete.  Tuning this to 1.0 would prevent reducers from fetching anything until all map tasks have completed.  That would cause a sudden burst of network bandwidth utilization when the last map task completes and the reducers start fetching.

Normally, the timing of reducers fetching map outputs should not alter the correctness of a MapReduce program.  This all happens internally in the MapReduce shuffle.  The data ultimately presented to your reducer code will be the same regardless of the timing of how the reducer fetched the map outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Until the map task is completed, nothing happens on the reducer side except the mapper output is copied over to reducer node. Reducer starts only after ALL the map tasks are completed. Is there a specific reason why you want to do that?

Comment: I'm implementing the algorithm canopy in order to find centroids in each mapper. once the mappers are done, I want to send them to the reducer and do canopy once again on the centroids from the mappers. for example, if mapper 1 found 3 centroids and each one has 30 points related. i want to send to reduce each centroid and the number of the related points. but since I know the number of the related points only after all mappers ran, I want to send the output only once the mappers ran.

Answer (score 1):

It's easily done by setting slowstart to 1.0.

Edit mapred-site.xml in:

Login as hadoop user

```
# vim ~/hadoopuser/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml <-- Hadoop 2.x

# vim ~/hadoopuser/hadoop/conf/hadoop/mapred-site.xml <-- Hadoop 1.x
```

and change value to 1.0 like below example:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps</name>
  <value>1.0</value>
  <description>The setting would start once all maps are finished </description>
</property>
```

This is valid for hadoop 1.2.1, 2.x and Cloudera.

In Cloudera V5.5.1 configuration under

```
 website: http://localhost:7180/cmf/services/10/config
 **Page 3**

 Number of Map Tasks to Complete Before Reduce Tasks
 mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps
```

Change from default value 0.05 to 1.0.